# Windows 10 перестала запускаться после Ccleaner

Tags: linux, windows

вчера я скачал программу defragler, вместе с ней установился ccleaner, я запустил дефрагментацию диска `S` и тем временем решил по-быстрому почистить пк через ccleaner (Потом я его собирался удалить). Почистил, диск дефрагментировался - всё окей.
Я выключаю пк.

Потом спустя время снова включаю пк - он запускается до экрана добро пожаловать, потом экран тухнет и сново эран добро пожаловать. И так бесконечно.

Я зашел в устранение неполадок через `F8`, там попробовал `sfc /scannow` - защита ресурсов windows не может выполнить данную операцию, потом запустил восстановление системы через точку восстановления, которую windows создала после удаления одной проги в этот же день. После восстановления при запуске системы - синий экран critical process died

Дальше я хотел откатится на более позднюю точку восстановления, но там была ошибка ,что нужно отключить защиту системы, чтобы восстановится.
Я в консоли пошарил, с помощью интернета вроде как что-то сделал, запустил всё-таки восстановление - не удалось восстановить систему.

Сейчас попробовал запустить сброс до заводских настроек.
Не удалось выполнить восстановление...

У меня на пк стоит 2 системы - windows 10 и ubuntu 20.04.
То есть у меня есть доступ к файлам винды. Я попробовал зайти через него в папку windows - ошибка Не удалось показать всё содержимое объекта "windows": Ошибка при получении информации о файле "media/username/hash/Windows/splwow64.exe": Ошибка ввода/вывода

но через консоль и sudo папка открылась без ошибок

Что мне делать? По какой причине это произошло.
Можно ли восстановить систему без потери файлов? Хотя бы на других дисках. И как её восстановить? Нужно на флешке образ сделать? Слетит ли от этого загрузчик linux?
Может можно через linux скачать и закинуть в windows поврежденные файлы?

Comment: сколько говорят - не запускай CCleaner, если не понимаешь, что оно делает. Теперь лучше переустановить систему, а потом поправить загрузчик grub.

Comment: Кто ж знал) Я запустил обычную чистку системы на главном экране и всё... Чистка походу была прям конкретная

Comment: да нет, просто удалило что то лишнее и все. Это как взять пылесос и пылесосить квартиру. в 90 процентах случаев все будет ок, ещё в 9 - чуть лишнее можно захватить. Но есть тот один процент случаев, где можно попортить сильно - например, на полу мега пазл собирали.

Comment: если есть время и желания, то можно попробовать все восстановить, и после этого другие "падения windows" будут уже не такими ужасными. Но только это вряд ли можно сделать через вопросы на SO да и время на это будет потрачено очень и очень много.

Comment: А куда мне еще можно написать? Вообще я бы даже с радостью винду переустановил ,тк она уже года 4 стоит не шелохнётся и уже изрядно подтормаживает, хотя пк у меня мощный, но мне хотелосьбы еще и файлы как-то сохранить

Comment: Во-первых, хранить информацию на системном разделе — изначально сомнительная затея. Во-вторых, перед переустановкой скопируйте их на другой диск/раздел наверное?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну с файлами как раз проблем не должно возникнуть, возьмите любой образ live загрузки, их в инете полным полно, даже виндовые есть, загрузитесь с него, и перетащите нужные вам данные, а систему проще установить в чистую, тем более что 4 года хороший срок :) уже пора бы обновиться.

Comment: Эм... Что? У меня система с 15го года стоит себе, и в ус не дует. Проблем никаких нет, нужно уметь нормально использовать ОС, и проблем не будет с ней практически никогда.